# Custom Observable stream of REST results from a list of links

Tags: rx-java

I am using a library which implements its own REST requests. It takes a 'permalink' and issues a REST request to fetch Content (I provide mocks in the source code for testing). I have a list of permalinks, and would like to schedule a request for each and generate a stream of Content results. All of it should be asynchronous, and once all results are done, I want to emit a list of them.

I am trying to achieve this using RxJava. Here is what I have now (sorry for not using lambdas, I just want to get used to the RxJava class names):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 10;
        List<String> permalinks = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
            permalinks.add("permalink_" + i);
        }

        ContentManager cm = new ContentManager();

        Observable
                .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Content>() {

                    int gotCount = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super Content> subscriber) {
                        for (String permalink : permalinks) { // 1. is iterating here the correct way?
                            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { // 2. how often and where should I check isUnsubscribed?
                                cm.getBasicContentByPermalink(permalink, new RestCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Content content) {
                                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                                            subscriber.onNext(content);
                                            completeIfFinished(); // 3. if guarded by isUnsubscribed, onComplete might never be called
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(int code, String message) {
                                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                                            subscriber.onNext(null); // 4. is this OK or is there some other way to mark a failure?
                                            completeIfFinished();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    private void completeIfFinished() {
                                        ++gotCount;
                                        if (gotCount == permalinks.size()) { // 5. how to know that the last request is done? am I supposed to implement such custom logic?
                                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .toList()
                .subscribe(new Action1<List<Content>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(List<Content> contents) {
                        System.out.println("list count: " + contents.size());
                        System.out.println("results: ");
                        contents.stream().map(content -> content != null ? content.basic : null).forEach(System.out::println);
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("finishing main");
    }
}

// library mocks

class Content {

    String basic;

    String extended;

    public Content(String basic, String extended) {
        this.basic = basic;
        this.extended = extended;
    }
}

interface RestCallback {

    void onSuccess(Content content);

    void onFailure(int code, String message);
}

class ContentManager {

    private final Random random = new Random();

    public void getBasicContentByPermalink(String permalink, RestCallback callback) {
        // just to simulate network latency and unordered results
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000) + 200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (random.nextInt(100) < 95) {
                    // 95% of the time we succeed
                    callback.onSuccess(new Content(permalink + "_basic", null));
                } else {
                    callback.onFailure(-1, permalink + "_basic_failure");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

This bit kind of works, but I am not sure if I do things the right way. Please take a look at the lines number 1-5:

1. When creating an Observable from a list, am I supposed to iterate
   over the list myself, or is there some other, better way? For
   instance, there is Observable.from(Iterable), but I don't think I
   can use it?
2. I am checking isUnsubscribed before I send the REST request, and
   also in both result handlers (success/failure). Is this the way it
   is supposed to be used?
3. I implement some logic to call onComplete when all requests have
   returned, no matter if successful or failed (see question 5). But, as they are
   guarded by the isUnsubscribed call, it may happen that they
   onComplete is never called. How does the stream know then that it
   should complete? Does it complete prematurely when the subscriber is unsubscribed and I don't have to think about it? Are there any caveats? For example, what would happen if the subscriber unsubscribed in the middle of emitting the Content results? In my tests, the list of all results is never emitted, but I would expect a list of all the results up to that point.
4. In the onFailure method, I emit null with onNext(null) to mark a
   failure. I do it because in the end I will have a zip of 2 streams,
   and will emit an instance of a custom class only when both zipped
   values are non null. Is this the correct way to do it?
5. As I mentioned, I have some custom logic to check if the stream is
   finished. What I do here is I count the REST results and when as
   many were processed as there are permalinks in the list, it is done.
   Is this necessary? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When creating an Observable from a list, am I supposed to iterate over the list myself, or is there some other, better way? For instance, there is Observable.from(Iterable), but I don't think I can use it?

Instead of iterating in the `create` method, you may build an observable per link.

```
public Observable<Content> getContent(permalink) {

    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                   ContentManager cm = new ContentManager();
                   if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { 
                            cm.getBasicContentByPermalink(permalink, new RestCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Content content) {
                                        subscriber.onNext(content);
                                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(int code, String message) {
                                       subscriber.onError(OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(new RuntimeException(message, permalink));
                                }

                }
    });
}
```

then use it with `flatMap` operator

```
 Observable.from(permalinks)
           .flatMap(link -> getContent(link))
           .subscribe();
```

> I am checking isUnsubscribed before I send the REST request, and also in both result handlers (success/failure). Is this the way it is supposed to be used?

check isUnsubscribed before you send your request is the way to do. No sure for this success/failure callback (I think it's useless but someone can say I'm wrong)

> I implement some logic to call onComplete when all requests have returned, no matter if successful or failed (see question 5). But, as they are guarded by the isUnsubscribed call, it may happen that they onComplete is never called.

If you Unsubscribe the stream, you'll stop to observe the stream, so you may not be notified of the completion of the stream.

> For example, what would happen if the subscriber unsubscribed in the middle of emitting the Content results?

you'll be able to consume what was emitted before unsubscribing.

> In the onFailure method, I emit null with onNext(null) to mark a failure. I do it because in the end I will have a zip of 2 streams, and will emit an instance of a custom class only when both zipped values are non null. Is this the correct way to do it?

nope. instead of null, emit an error (using `onError` on the subscriber).
Using this, you won't have to check null in your zip lambda. Just zip !

> As I mentioned, I have some custom logic to check if the stream is finished. What I do here is I count the REST results and when as many were processed as there are permalinks in the list, it is done. Is this necessary? Is this the right way?

If you want to get the number of permalink, when the stream is completed, you can use `count` operator.

```
Observable.from(permalinks)
          .flatMap(link -> getContent(link))
          .count()
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you want to emit number of link, at the end of a sucessfull link, you can try `scan` operator

```
 Observable.from(permalinks)
          .flatMap(link -> getContent(link))
          .map(content -> 1) // map content to 1 in order to count it.
          .scan((seed, acu) -> acu + 1) 
          .subscribe(System.out::println); // will print 2, 3...
```

Comment: I tried from/flatMap myself but I made an error, your code helped me do it properly, I prefer this way, don't need my custom logic to detect completion, thank you! In the line subscriber.onError(OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(new RuntimeException("failed"), permalink)); I get:  Exception in thread "Thread-7" rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: failed, and never see any emissions from the stream. I don't thin this is the way to go. I will simply not call onNext and then call onCompleted, which will convert the permalink to 0 Contents. I won't even need a filter for nulls.

Comment: 'you'll be able to consume what was emitted before unsubscribing.' When I implement my RestCallback#onFailure to call subscriber.unsubscribe(), I never see any emission, no matter how many succeeded - I can see that some succeeded simply by putting a Sysout in the onSuccess method. This is caused by the 'toList' call. When I don't wait for the whole list but rather process each emission on its own, I get the successful ones up to the failure point. But I do need it to be a list.

Comment: you SOULD use onError instead of onCompleted to notify of an error.
If you want to detect the error, you'll to implemente the onError callback : ‘Observable.error(new RuntimeException("oups").subscribe(System.out::println, (e) -> System.err.println("ERROR ->" + e.getMessage());‘.

This will, you'll be abble to manage errors in your stream (using onErrorResumeNext method, ...)

Comment: toList will emit a list only then when stream is completed. As it doesn't complete, it doesn't emit a list. If you want a partial list of emitted items, you'll have to transform each Content into a list of one item, and then combine it using scan. it will emit a list that grow each time a remote call succedd.

Comment: In case an error occurs, I just want to log and not emit any value, and go on with the ones I do get successfully. I don't want to have an exception thrown and cancel the whole stream just because one REST request failed. Currently, this seems to be the case. I will have to check the new snippet to see what it does.

Comment: Just deal with errors then : Observable.from(permalinks)
           .flatMap(link -> getContent(link).doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Get Exception : " + e).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()).

This example shallow the error of network call to the main stream. So the stream will continue and ignore the error.

Comment: Doesn't this (onErrorResumeNext(empty())) just stop the observable after the first error occurs? I just want to log and otherwise ignore the error - why not just log it in the RestCallback onFailure() method and not emit anything? Is this approach wrong? It is definitely simple enough...

Comment: The getContent() stream will be stopped. Not the "main stream". (Please note that the onerrorresumenext is on getContent() stream !). It's the way to do. Otherwise : how to know if you encounter an error or if the stream is completed ?

Comment: Ah, my mistake was that I was calling onError() etc. on the main stream, from Observable.from(permalinks). It all works as you say it does once called on correct streams. Now I get it, thank you.

Comment: About the isUnsubscribed() questions - if I don't wrap the subscriber.onNext/onCompeted etc. in it after the reply is back, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: This instance has been unsubscribed and the queue is no longer usable. when I use take(3), for example. So I guess it is really necessary to check the status before calling subscriber methods, and checking it before sending a request is just nice to have.